# Lock screen implementation: Disable navigation buttons and notification access

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, navigationbar, lockscreen

I am building a Lock Screen that doesn't replace the stock Lock Screen, but instead allows the user to use "Swipe" to unlock and then shows my Lock Screen.

Therefore, I would like to know how I could possibly launch the Lock Screen immediately after the user has swiped to unlock, as a non dismissible activity.

By setting the activity's category as home, I was able to restrict some functionality but not entirely as the user could pull down the notification panel and enter apps or even press the recents apps button.